# Counting Principles. Numbers not divisible by $5$

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers between $101$ and $800$ inclusive are not divisible by $5$?
Should be done using factorials and nCr.

Comment: why on earth would you use factorials and nCr?

Comment: That requirement about factorials and binomial coefficients seems to be pretty unreasonable as any *real* number $\;r\;$  can be wrriten as $\;r\binom nn=r\cdot nCn\;$ .

Comment: @Joffan I assumed that he meant "using elementary counting methods", hence my answer.

Comment: perhaps so, but even then, no factorials and no nCr ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is not divisible by 5 if its last digit is not equal to 0 or 5. The number 800 is divisible by 5, so we might as well count up to 799.

The first digit is then chosen among 1-7, the second can be anything, the last one from 8 (not 0,5). This gives us $7 \times 10 \times 8$ numbers. (Note that we don't count 100 automatically so starting from 101 is no problem.)

Comment: You have accidentally included all the 8XX numbers... Note you could also go directly for the not-divisible-by-5 numbers in this typographic approach.

Comment: You are quite correct, I'll adapt!

Comment: Shouldn't the second digit only be 1-9 not 1-10?

Comment: @AlexFeklisov 202 is OK, isn't it. 0 should be included.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

The number of intgers in $\in[101,800]$ divisible by $5$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac{800}5\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{101}5\right\rfloor$$

There are $800-101+1=700$ numbers altogether

Can you find the complement set?